# Non standard stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I don't know how to deal with the following stochastic integral:

$\int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{t-s+1}} d W(s)$

As you can see, the variable $t$ appears both as an endpoint of the interval of integration and in the integrand. And that's exactly the problem. In general, the stochastic integral of a deterministic function is a normal random variable, but here? What can we say?

What about its stochastic differential? Is it possible to apply Ito formula to that process?

Could you find a way to, somehow, take the variable $t$ outside the integral? In this way we could apply Ito formula without problems

Thank you very much for any help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $t$, the function $f:s\mapsto 1/\sqrt{t-s+1}$ is an element of $L^2[0,t]$, so the stochastic integral $X_t:=\int_0^t{1\over\sqrt{t-s+1}}\,dW(s)=\int_0^t f(s)\,dW(s)$ is defined and is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance
$$
\int_0^t{1\over t-s+1}\,ds=\log(t+1).
$$
If $0<t<u$ then the covariance of $X_t$ and $X_u$ is 
$$
\int_0^t{1\over\sqrt{(u-s+1)(t-s+1)}}\,ds=\log\left({t+u+2+2\sqrt{(t+1)(u+1)}\over u-t+2+2\sqrt{u-t+1}}\right).
$$
(Integration courtesy of WolframAlpha.) This means that
$$
\Bbb E[(X_{t+h}-X_t)^2] ={t\over 2(t+1)}h+o(1),\qquad h\to 0
$$
(if my calculation is correct) from which it follows that $t\mapsto X_t$ has a modification that is Holder continuous of order $\alpha$ for any $\alpha\in(0,1/2)$.

A formal integration by parts reveals that 
$$
X_t=W(t)+\int_0^t {W(s)\over 2(t-s+1)^{3/2}}\,ds,
$$
and so (the continuous modification of) $X_t$ is a continuous semimartingale with martingale part $W(t)$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer. My doubt is exactly this one: is it right to say $\int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{t-s+1}} dW(s) = \int_0^t f(s) d W(s)$? I am not so sure about that..

Comment: For a fixed time interval $[0,t]$ and a non-random function $f\in L^2[0,t]$, the Ito integral $\int_0^t f(s)dW(s)$ is well-defined, and has the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\int_0^t [f(s)]^2\,ds$. You can find this fact in any introduction to the Ito intgeral. Now simply apply this fact to the function $f(s) = f_t(s) = {1\over\sqrt{t-s+1}}$, $s\in[0,t]$. In this construction, $t$ is held fixed and plays the role of a parameter.